# Как скрыть часть полей в админке flask_admin, на уровне списка. При этом, поля записи должны отражаться на странице редактирования?

Tags: python, flask, flask-admin, field

Как скрыть часть полей в админке **flask_admin**, на уровне списка. При этом, поля записи должны отражаться на странице редактирования полностью? Смысл в том, чтобы вывод списка был более компактным.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вам необходим `column_list` регулирует отображаемые колонки ( [подробнее тут](https://flask-admin.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/mod_model/#flask_admin.model.BaseModelView.column_list))

Те поля которые должны быть на странице формы (добавление, редактирования), указываются в `form_columns` ([подробнее тут](https://flask-admin.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/mod_model/#flask_admin.model.BaseModelView.form_columns))

```
from flask_admin.contrib.sqla import ModelView

class AdminPost(ModelView):
    column_list = (
        Post.name.key,
        Post.address.key,
        ...,
    )
    form_columns = (
        Post.name.key,
        ...,
    )

    def __init__(self, session, **kwargs):
        super(AdminPost, self).__init__(Post, session, **kwargs)
```